# Process cannot access the file "MyFile.log" because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am getting

> The process cannot access the file "MyFile.log" because it is being used by another process.

while I am doing this

```
File.SetAttributes(filename,FileAttributes.Normal)

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    // Do stuff with log4net log
}
```

I have read other posts but they all suggest what I am already doing. Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio is locking the file. Try restart it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try to configure log4net with a minimal lock:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    ...
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
   ...
</appender>
```

[have a look here for better explanation.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Alternatively, try to open the log file with:

```
     using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {...
}
```

or check this project:[Tailf](https://github.com/FelicePollano/tailf)
In any case, remove the SetAttributes() part that could not work.
*Tailf Project Description
Tailf is a C# implementation of the tail -f command available on unix/linux systems. Differently form other ports it does not lock the file in any way so it works even if other rename the file: **this is expecially designed to works well with log4net rolling file appender.***

Comment: Cannot configure/touch the configuration in place. Any more Ideas.About to read your link

Comment: @user231465 check the improved reply

Comment: Cannot download now at work but can you read the file somehow? Was thinking in making a copy of the file .I wonder how the commercial log Reader handles the locking mmm......

Comment: The FileShare.Delete worked.What are the implication of FileShare.Delete?

Comment: FileShare.Read is probably the one that solved your issue. FileShare.Delete allow log4net to rename the file when it "roll" the file name.

Comment: Adding <lockingModel type=... /> did it for me.