# Creating zip from Log4Net Log files causes System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, zip, log4net

I am using a simple code snippet to create a zip file from the log4net log files. See the code below.

```
var logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(log4netfolderName, "*.log*");
 using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(destinationDirectory.DirectoryPath  + "Test.zip", 
 ZipArchiveMode.Create))
 {
     foreach (var file in logFiles)
     {
         zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, 
         Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
     } 
 }
```

The problem is the log4net is currently using the log file and I get a *"**The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process." (System.IO.IOException)***

Also I cannot change the log4net config to use a minimal lock as given in [Process cannot access the file "MyFile.log" because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710110/process-cannot-access-the-file-myfile-log-because-it-is-being-used-by-another) or dont know how to use FileStream on the [ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class. How Should I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can read the whole files and not *create the entry from file* but *from scratch* using a file stream. I don't know right now, it's just an assumption.

Comment: Sorry don't want to create a temporary file and clean it, that would be my last resort...

Comment: This is your understanding of what I suggested you. There's no temp file in the suggested approach...

Comment: in here `zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file` file refers to the file path but not the files. Zip file CreateEntry overloads accepts only file names but not files. Hence my assumption.

Comment: If you are suggesting to Dump the usage of ZipFile altogether and write my own approach, may be then you are right which is going to be a daunting task :D

Comment: I've not published an answer because I don't know if what I was suggesting would work with this ZIP API. But maybe there's other which accepts a `Stream` instead of a file path, and this doesn't mean that you need to do your own library from scratch...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61088/discussion-between-carbinecoder-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the [ZipFileExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and used its code to re-write mine. The fix goes like this, feel free to correct or improve my answer.

```
var logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderName,"*.log.*");
using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(destinationDirectory.DirectoryPath + "Test.zip",
ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (var file in logFiles)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var zipArchiveEntry = zip.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(file),
                CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var destination1 = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                stream.CopyTo(destination1);
        }
    }
}
```